# Storage Client ListObjects

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

My application requires to download files from Google cloud storage bucket.

I'm downloading files from GCS bucket using StorageClient ListObjects method.

In `ListObjects` I want to provide file name in regular expression format.

Currently I'm using below code.

```
var listFiles = storageClientVariable.ListObjects(GCSBucketName, 
                folderPrefix).Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(p.Name, regexFileName));

foreach (var objectName in listFiles)
{
     bucketFileName = Path.GetFileName(objectName.Name);
     guidFolderPath = localPath + "\\" + bucketFileName;

     FileStream fs = new FileStream(guidFolderPath, FileMode.Create);
                     using (fs)
                     {
                        var progress = new Progress<IDownloadProgress>(
                          p => { DownloadProgress(p); });
                        storage.DownloadObject(GCSBucketName, objectName.Name, fs, option, progress);
                     }                     
}
break;
```

This code works fine. But I'm passing regexFileName in Enumerable.Where method. Which loops through all the files present in bucket. So is there any other way present where I can avoid extra looping? Or Is there any better way of downloading file from GCS bucket using c# code?

Comment: What could be "better" in your opinion? That code looks like it would work or do you get any error message?

Comment: @digijay This code works fine. But I'm passing regexFileName in Enumerable.Where method. Which loops through all the files present in bucket. So is there any other way present where I can avoid extra looping?

Comment: Ah okay, that makes it clearer, though I don't know a better way to solve this. You should maybe add that comment directly to the question (using the edit button) for other people reading this question, so it get's more clarity (and relevance). And *Welcome to StackOverflow!*

Comment: And i would recommend to delete the [double post](https://serverfault.com/questions/992871/storage-client-listobjects-method), people here don't approve of this :-)

Answer (score 2):

As @eespinola noted, you can specify a prefix on the ListObjects request. If your regex happens to start with a non-regex special character (i.e., other than '[', ']', '*', etc.) you could build a prefix query for that part and then do the remaining filtering using the regex as you're doing now. gsutil works like this, e.g., if you do:

```
gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/abc[0-9]*
```

it will use "abc" as the prefix, and then do the remaining filtering client-side.

Answer (score 1):

As you can check in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects), using the official API you can list all the objects from a GCS bucket, or list objects with a given prefix. However, you can not use regexFilename in order to optimize your code.

Furthermore, you can check code samples in C# in this [Github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/Storage/Storage.cs).

The only way I think it can be done is actually the same as you are doing it now.